# Scheduling and fetching data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on an application that fetched data from X remote API's. 
Currently I'm running a cron job every 2 minutes that executes a rake task for each of the API's but I feel that even if this is a simple solution it won't be the best solution for me.

What happens if the rake task has not completed before the next one is executed?
How do I now that the tasks are run correctly?
Questions like this is why I want to switch from cron.

Do you guys have any ideas or best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Add lockrun on your cron job. Lockrun checks that the cron is running or not. If running then it doesn't start another same cron job.

Comment: That sounds like a valid approach if I stick to cron

Answer (score 0):

Look at [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem. I'm personally didn't work with it, but heard that it is good solution.

Comment: I've looked at delayed job and indeed, it looks nice but I still have to schduele the task.